# Automatically Show If Username Available With JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, html, forms

I am trying to see if a username has already been taken in a mysql database and it does not seem to want to work. Ideally it would show as I was typing on the form. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I do not see anything wrong with the code.

On my main page is the code for the jquery, javascript and html.
The corresponding page is testusername.php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#feedback').load('testusername.php').show();
$('#username_input').keyup(function() {
$.post('testusername.php', { username:form.username.value }, 
function(result) {
$('#feedback').html(result).show();
});
});
});
</script>

<form name='form'>
<fieldset>
<legend>Test Form</legend>
Username: <br /><input type='text' id='username_input' name='username'></input>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id = "feedback"></div>
```

testusername.php is:

```
<?php 
include 'functions2.php';
?>
<?php
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$query1a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query1a);
if ($count==0)
{
echo "Available";   
}
else {
echo "Username exists";
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions! They are obsolete and you should use PDO instead. Also, on a point of style, use `SELECT EXISTS...` to do a check of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should work to handle your client side part, Assuming you have jQuery loaded to your pafe properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#username_input').keyup(function() {
     $.post('testusername.php', { username: $(this).val() },function(result){
      $('#feedback').html(result).show();
     });
   });
});
</script>
```

For the server side, dont use * in the query. You may use something like `SELECT 1 FROM ....` Also you may want to make sure you are not going to be a victim of [SQL Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).